# Call inherited method using some "specialized" fields

Tags: c++, inheritance, code-reuse

For example:

```
struct A {
    ~A() {
        cout << me << ": destructor" << endl;
    }
    const string me = "A";
};

struct B : A {
    const string me = "B";
};

int main() {
    {
        A a;
        B b;
    }
    cout << "----\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for the newbie question, I'm just wondering for the following output:

```
A: destructor
A: destructor
----
```

In the second line I was expecting `B: destructor`. Can you explain why? How can I modify the code without rewriting the destructor in order to see the expected result?

Comment: `A::me` is completely unrelated to `B::me`. They are separate variables, and `A` doesn't know anything about `B::me`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declaration B::me shadows A::me, but A::~A, obviously, uses A::me. (you should read more about ctors and dtors, in particular why virtual functions should not be called in ctors and dtors for deeper understanding). As for how example should be corrected:

```
struct A{
  string me;
  A(string str = "A") : me(str){}
  ~A(){cout<<me<<endl;}
}

struct B : A {
  B(string str = "B") : A(str){}
}
```